# Getting filtered list values from all users in my firebase Realtime-Database where the list is a child of user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my firebase real-time database looks like.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "PDFZ0QOoTxYbCyruOrbiA2y1n5O2" : {
      "email" : "mark@outlook.com",
      "name" : "Mark Evans",
      "paymentMethods" : {
        "-ML5oMsCnXgfBRCh7DdO" : {
          "paymentProvider" : "Google Pay",
          "phone" : "+915555555555",
          "userName" : "Mark Evans"
        },
        "-ML5oRHklHHIK33NQowD" : {
          "paymentProvider" : "BHIM",
          "phone" : "+911111111111",
          "userName" : "Chris Evans"
        }
      },
      "uid" : "PDFZ0QOoTxYbCyruOrbiA2y1n5O2"
    },

    "epyBsLU0fYOT8uc0Bo698f5SRcO2" : {
      "email" : "axle@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Axle Blaze",
      "paymentMethods" : {
        "-ML5o5Zv_3ZixCIXWBqg" : {
          "paymentProvider" : "Google Pay",
          "phone" : "+918888888888",
          "userName" : "Axle Blaze"
        },
        "-ML5o9pMNucaacdU0G3P" : {
          "paymentProvider" : "BHIM",
          "phone" : "+911111111111",
          "userName" : "Bunny Blaze"
        }
      },
      "uid" : "epyBsLU0fYOT8uc0Bo698f5SRcO2"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get those payment options where phone number = "+91XXXXXXXXXX" no matter from which user payment option belongs to.

For example: If i need all payment options where phone == +911111111111

Result should be :

```
"-ML5oRHklHHIK33NQowD" : {
          "paymentProvider" : "BHIM",
          "phone" : "+911111111111",
          "userName" : "Chris Evans"
        },
"-ML5o9pMNucaacdU0G3P" : {
          "paymentProvider" : "BHIM",
          "phone" : "+911111111111",
          "userName" : "Bunny Blaze"
        }
```

I have to do this in Android but since querying should be similar for any platform so I need help with how the query should be structured.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase queries work on a flat list. The value you order/filter on must be in a fixed location under each direct child node of `users`.

In your current structure, you can:

1. Search across all users for direct properties of that user, such as their email or name.
2. Search across the payment methods of a specific users.

The query you want is not possible on your current data structure. If you want to allow a query across all payment methods of all users, you'll need to change (or augment) your data structure to (also) have a flat list of payment methods across all users.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Frank, I will try to make a flat structure by adding a new child in the table named payment options and keeping all payment options there for easy retrieval. I will accept your answer in 1-2 days if no better solution is found. Thanks again!